# Complex JavaScript. What called me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, callstack

Project I'm working on uses jQuery.

I have a series of Ajax calls being made that load() other HTML fragments which in turn load() other fragments. The whole thing is confusing. I didn't write the code.

Is there any tool which will allow me to walk the callstack so I can figure what is calling a method? any browser tools that would help me figure this out?

**Resolution:**
In the end this was being caused because a <script src="..." was being injected in the server-side code. Your suggestions really helped - it was a combination of those and temporarily setting Ajax to sync instead async that helped me track down the issue.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});
```

Comment: Javascript is so much fun to debug isn't it?  I don't know of any tools that let you monitor the the stack, and add break points to check stuff.  The best debugger I have used for JS is firebug: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/

Comment: @Jay, I use VS2008 and set JS code breakpoints all the time.

Comment: Note that ajax methods will be hard do debug due to its asynchronous nature - the returning calls will not be on the same stack as the invoking calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) is capable of this.

When the debugger is paused, Firebug shows you the call stack, which is the set of nested function calls that are currently running and waiting to return.

The call stack is represented as a compact strip of buttons in the toolbar, each with the name of a function on the stack. You can click any button to jump to the line where that function is paused, and look at the local variables inside that function.

Comment: You can also use "console.trace()" from the console itself to see the detailed call stack once the debugger is paused.

Comment: How do I pause at the exact right moment? Is there a console.pause?

Comment: or should I just throw an alert inside the function in question?

Comment: With Firebug, you can add a breakpoint to the line in question. Open the Script tab and double click on the line number.

Comment: My problem is this app loads a default.aspx page and then everything else is a fake modal (via jQuery) so the Script tab doesn't show me anything useful.

Comment: You can also call `console.trace()` directly from your code, so you don't even need to use the debugger.

Answer (score 7):

Chrome also has a [pretty wicked debugger](http://www.chromium.org/devtools) built-in under Developer Tools, no add-ons/extensions needed.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for firebug.  you can pause the debugger to walk the call stack
http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try Opera's Dragonfly (available in any recent Opera build). I find it less refined than Firebug, but some errors are much more explicit under it.